# Gnome-Shell 3.4 Themes not working in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

Even themes advertised as Gnome-shell 3.4 compatible have graphical issues on Gnome-Shell 3.4. The main thing is that the text is black and nearly invisible, and the icons in the applications screen are crowded and in some cases overlapping. The themes did not do this before upgrade, and the default doesn't do it now. I am using user theme extension, and the themes I have tried are the Ambiance-Color set and London Smoke (both of which are advertised as 3.4 compatible).

Comment: Please add the method you used for installing you themes in your question (and what theme are you using?)

Comment: Edited, now can you answer?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right way to get gnome-tweak-tool (advanced settings) to work therefore shell themes and extensions to work **WITHOUT** breaking your gnome shell

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-common
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing
(type N and press enter at the end of the process)
```

Restart the shell (Alt F2 >> r >> enter)

Comment: Didn't work, and may or may not have broken my system (Some errors while installing, hopefully nothing serious). Appears to be fighting for supremacy with a package in a ppa I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Gnome Shell themes are currently incompatible with Gnome 3.4, the same for some extensions.
You can look for updated themes on Deviantart for instance.

I'm currently using this theme which works pretty well.
http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/04/orion-gtk3-and-gnome-shell-elegance.html

Comment: I specified in the question that these themes were 3.4 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, first delete older themes in .themes directory before installing the new one, otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: Tried, both .themes and /usr/share/themes/, still got the graphical errors.